# org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner Not found

Tags: java, spring

In my spring project, I import all the external jars to WEB-INF/lib folder, After that my project stopped compiling. I am not able to compile any more. A error coming when i am trying to compile. I tried every thing but not working.

Here is my logs:-

```
Jun 24, 2015 12:38:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
Jun 24, 2015 12:38:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig getServletContainerInitializer
SEVERE: The ServletContentInitializer [org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner] could not be created
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.getServletContainerInitializer(ContextConfig.java:1652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1562)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1270)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Jun 24, 2015 12:38:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processServletContainerInitializers
SEVERE: Failed to process JAR found at URL [jar:file:/home/east/workspace/jspworkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/SpringFileUpload/WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet.jsp-2.3.1-sources.jar!/] for ServletContainerInitializers for context with name [/SpringFileUpload]
Jun 24, 2015 12:38:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig configureStart
SEVERE: Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s)
Jun 24, 2015 12:38:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags is already defined
Jun 24, 2015 12:38:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags/form is already defined
Jun 24, 2015 12:38:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
Jun 24, 2015 12:38:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/SpringFileUpload] startup failed due to previous errors
Jun 24, 2015 12:38:05 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 24, 2015 12:38:05 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 24, 2015 12:38:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1868 ms
```

What i tried:-

```
 1.) there is no servet-api.jar in my WEB_INF/lib folder
 2.) Remove all spring jars from lib folder which i require to compile project.
 3.) Put jetty.jar in lib folder but not working.
```

Comment: Are you under the eclipse platform?

Comment: have you tried using maven for dependency management? Sounds like one the jars you've added manually is causing this error.

Comment: Yes, I am under eclipse.

Comment: Yes, But how i know, there is lots of jars file. @KorhanOzturk

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the jetty's dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.orbit</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.v201112011158</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.orbit</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.jasper.glassfish</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.v201112011158</version>
    </dependency>
```

worked for me.

Comment: can i add jar instead of adding these in pom.xml?

Comment: Sure, as always you can the jars into the classpath manually. I've not tried to put them into the tomcat's lib directory though.

Comment: I download first jar http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/orbit/javax.servlet/3.0.0.v201112011016/ and compile by giving reference from download folder. But still not working

Comment: @RenuThakur What jar have you downloaded? `javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar`?

Comment: @RenuThakur If so, the just doesn't contain the class. You need http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/orbit/org.apache.jasper.glassfish/2.2.2.v201112011158/ instead. And one more thing, don't download the very first jar, it's just javadocs. Find org.apache.jasper.glassfish-2.2.2.v201112011158.jar instead.

Answer (score 0):

I just move my whole lib folder to out of project, 
And after that give reference of jars. Move required jars to web-inf/lib folder, And after that error doesn't come.

This fix the error.